# how to detect a duplicate entry in vb.net and mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem in vb.net and using mysql database .
I already have a save button code but my problem is I need to detect the duplicate data. I tried searching for it but it won't work with my codes there is always a error or warning.
My question is through this code where I put the code in detecting a duplicate entry?

```
con = New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; database=db; uid=root;pwd="
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "insert into paraiso_dbms2.client_t(FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME,LASTNAME,GENDER,BIRTHDATE,AGE,STREET,BARANGAY,CITY,ZIPCODE,PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES('" & txtfirstname.Text & "','" & txtmidname.Text & "','" & txtlastn.Text & "','" & gender & "','" & dpbd.Text & "','" & txtage.Text & "','" & txtstreet.Text & "','" & txtbrgy.Text & "','" & txtcity.Text & "','" & txtzipcode.Text & "','" & txtphone.Text & "')"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Sucessfully!")
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Dispose()
End Try
load_table()
```

Comment: _"there is always a error or warning"_ you think it's not realated or important for your question?

Comment: also try to check the `query` value. probably insert sintaxis is wrong.

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `ExecuteReader` is not for inserting data; dont concat SQL, use SQL params so you can pass the actual typed data than all strings.  See also: [Ask]

Comment: @Plutonix Actually, I don't know for `mySql` provider, but with Sqlclient you can use `ExecuteReader/ExecuteNonquery` with `OUTPUT` to get `INSERTED` or `DELETED`

Comment: Use google for "mySql Upsert". You will find answer for all your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

you should update the current code of inserting to this below

```
con = New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; database=db; uid=root;pwd="
Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "insert into paraiso_dbms2.client_t(FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME,LASTNAME,GENDER,BIRTHDATE,AGE,STREET,BARANGAY,CITY,ZIPCODE,PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES('" & txtfirstname.Text & "','" & txtmidname.Text & "','" & txtlastn.Text & "','" & gender & "','" & dpbd.Text & "','" & txtage.Text & "','" & txtstreet.Text & "','" & txtbrgy.Text & "','" & txtcity.Text & "','" & txtzipcode.Text & "','" & txtphone.Text & "')"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    MessageBox.Show("Saved Sucessfully!")
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Dispose()
End Try
load_table()
```

and how to check if record exist you can compare the phone number with phone number textbox since there is no unique number or email

```
con = New MySqlConnection
con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; database=db; uid=root;pwd="
Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "select PHONE_NUMBER from paraiso_dbms2.client_t where PHONE_NUMBER='" & txtphone.Text & "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
   dim count as string = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    MessageBox.Show(count)
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Dispose()
End Try
```

even im not sure if this will work for you because i didnt see the whole code if not ill give you new